# xpath conditionals not working with xmllint

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I am trying to use a conditional to filter some nodes of the following XML using xpath.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="video_wrapper">
  <div class="stretchy-wrapper">
    <video width="1280px" height="720px">
      <source src="video-480p.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="480P" res="480"/>
      <source src="video-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="720P" res="720"/>
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="1080P" res="1080"/> 
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This XPath works:

```
xmllint --xpath "//source" ./scratch.xml
<source src="video-480p.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="480P" res="480"/>
<source src="video-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="720P" res="720"/>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="1080P" res="1080"/>
```

However this does not:

```
xmllint --xpath "//source[@res='1000']" ./scratch.xml
XPath set is empty
```

Is my syntax somehow wrong?

P.S. The version of libxml on my system is `20904`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//source[@res='1000']` selects nothing because your document has no such `source` element.

Perhaps you meant

```
//source[@res='1080']
                 ^
```

which selects

```
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="1080P" res="1080"/>
```

Comment: Oh my... you are correct!!!! I guess I need to up the font in my terminal or something, the 8 looked like a 0 in my eyes.  Thank you.